# Attach ref to contentContainer of <ScrollView>

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get a `ref` attached to the inner view of a `<ScrollView>` is this possible?

Doing the following attaches ref to the parent view. But I want the inner content. Here is some pseudo-code below:

```
const parentRef = useRef();
const contentRef = useRef(); // This is what I'm

<ScrollView
  // This get's parent just fine
  ref={parentRef}
  // This below doesn't work of course
  contentContainerRef={contentRef}
/>
```

Is it possible to get a ref on that contentContainer?

Answer (score 0):

There's an undocumented prop called `innerViewRef`:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/2c5a966054c2a80d63aa9c2c2a234a80a02918cf/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L657-L660

This works:

```
const parentRef = useRef();
const contentRef = useRef();

<ScrollView
  ref={parentRef}
  innerViewRef={contentRef}
/>
```